# Visual Studio For Mac Cordova

Tags: visual-studio

I have 2 computer
First one is IMac and the second one is Windows10 
I use visual studio + cordova to finish my android apps
and right now i am trying to install cordova in visual studio for mac 
but I cant find any topic like this or documentation

sorry for my broken English 
Please help me

Comment: Please add a detailed description for your problem.

Comment: ok , when i am using windows , If i install visual studio it will automatically let me choose which tools that i wish to install , but in visual studio for mac there is no such options to let me install apache cordova

Comment: anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer myself...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/ios-guide
share this for somebody who have same question as me

Comment: I want to do the same. but in the link above it links VS on windows with macbook. I am looking to use cordova directly on macbook

Comment: The link explains only how to build your Cordova app for iOS using the Mac only to compile with Xcode. You cannot install the Tools for Apache Cordova on the Visual Studio for Mac version, ergo you still need to use the Windows machine for this.